# Preserving alpha when blitting

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

How can I preserve alpha values when blitting? I want to blit multiple black squares with various alpha values onto a surface and then blit that surface onto the screen. Everything I try just blits a solid opaque black surface.

Edit:

What I want is this:

[image: wanted]

What I'm getting is this:

[image: getting this]

The code

```
#include <SDL.h>

void putPixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel){

  Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels;
  pixels[(y * surface->w) + x] = pixel;
}

void FillAlpha(SDL_Surface* Surface){
  Uint32 Pixel;
  Uint8 RGBA[4] = {0, 0, 0, 100};
  Pixel = RGBA[3]<<24 | RGBA[2]<<16 | RGBA[1]<<8 | RGBA[0];
  for(int x=0; x<32; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<32; y++){
      putPixel(Surface, x, y, Pixel);
    }
  }
  RGBA[3] = 150;
  Pixel = RGBA[3]<<24 | RGBA[2]<<16 | RGBA[1]<<8 | RGBA[0];
  for(int x=32; x<64; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<32; y++){
      putPixel(Surface, x, y, Pixel);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  SDL_Window* Window = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* Screen = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* Alpha = NULL;

  SDL_Event Event;

  bool Quit = false;

  Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Alpha test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 128, 128, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if(Window == NULL) return 1;
  Screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(Window);
  if(Screen == NULL) return 2;

  Alpha = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, 64, 32, 32,
                               Screen->format->Rmask, Screen->format->Gmask,
                               Screen->format->Bmask, Screen->format->Amask);
  if(Alpha == NULL) return 3;
  SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(Alpha, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
  FillAlpha(Alpha);

  while(!Quit){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
      if(Event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
        if(Event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
          Quit = true;
        }
      }else if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT){
        Quit = true;
      }
    }
    SDL_FillRect(Screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Screen->format, 255, 255, 255));
    SDL_BlitSurface(Alpha, NULL, Screen, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);
  }

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code, including the part where you create the surface(s), and the copying?  I expect you're using surfaces with differing pixel formats, but we'll have to see the code to know.

Comment: I've found a way to make sure that the alpha is correctly added to the surface, but it doesn't blend correctly to the screen on any blendmode.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on alpha blending:  http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/13_alpha_blending/index.php .  Now, I know this is not exactly what you're doing, but it might be a place to start:  get Lazy Foo's version going, then change to your own kind of surface.

Comment: The setSurfaceAlphaMod is the problem, I have to use it for blending to happen, and then it overwrites all of the surface's alpha.